# When reading from binary file, loop stops midway, all good up till then

Tags: c, file, binary, scanf

I'm trying to read an *arr_size* number of integers from a binary file "file.bin" to a dynamic array *arr*. The first number in the file is the *arr_size* value, which is read correctly. Then the loop iterates through an *arr_size* number of values, first 5 values are read correctly, then the program stops abruptly and the printf after the fscanf doesn't print out anything. No errors or warnings, no nothing.
This is how I call the function:

```
loadFromFile(&size, &m2);
```

The function itself:

```
void loadFromFile (int *arr_size, int **arr) {
   FILE *file = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
   fscanf(file, "%d", arr_size);
   (*arr) = (int *) malloc ((*arr_size) * sizeof(int));
   for (int i = 0; i < *arr_size; i++) {
       printf("i=%d, ", i);
       fscanf(file, "%d", arr[i]);
       printf("%d \n", *arr[i]);
   }
   fclose(file);
}
```

Output is this:

```
i=0, 928
i=1, 604
i=2, 113
i=3, 37
i=4, 193
i=5,
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include how you are calling loadFromFile() and an example of the file contents. Reading binary file with `fscanf()` sounds strange, because it is designed to read ASCII text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with your pointer access:

```
(*arr) = (int *) malloc ((*arr_size) * sizeof(int));
```

`arr` is assumed to point to a variable of type `int*`. This sets `*arr` to the allocated array.

```
fscanf(file, "%d", arr[i]);
```

This treats `arr` as if it is an array of pointers, instead of a pointer to a pointer to an array.

```
printf("%d \n", *arr[i]);
```

This is consistent with `scanf()` invocation above. However, both of them access memory out-of-bounds, after the `int* arr` variable in the caller, instead of using the freshly allocated array.

You'll want to use `&(*arr)[i]` for `scanf()` and `(*arr)[i]` for `printf()`. Or to actually make it readable and not prone to errors, write it like this:

```
int *dest = malloc ((*arr_size) * sizeof(int));
*arr = dest;
fscanf(..., &dest[i]);
printf(..., dest[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! How else would you recommend reading the binary file if not with fscanf?

Comment: @ausavi If `fscanf()` does what you want it to do, it just means that your file is not really "binary" as the term would normally be used: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file . For real binary files, you would use `fread()`.